# Question based on circles?

Tags: circles

In a circle, ABCD is a cyclic quadrilateral and PQ is a diameter. PQ intersects the side AD and BC. Prove that QC and AP bisect Angle C and Angle A respectively.

Comment: A [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eJxsK.png) would be very helpful. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be true.

Comment: I think it is the other way around, i.e., if you consider the bisectors of C and A then their intersections with the circle always identify a diameter.